# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer With Specific Value Parser

Tags: java, spring, configuration, properties-file

I understand that the `${...}`-notation works as long as it contains references to other properties. However, I want to extend that parsing algorithm.

Here's the properties-file:

```
connection.http.connectTimeout=15000
#connection.http.readTimeout=${connection.http.connectTimeout}
connection.http.readTimeout=%{30*1000}
```

The second line would still work and set `readTimeout` to 15000, but I want to make line 3 work. I have to say that I don't care what prefix and postfix I use, the above example uses `%{...}`, but whatever makes it work is fine with me. `${...}` might be the better choice as all the required parsing exists already, but then my new algorithm has to kick in before the usual Spring-stuff.

Here's what I have so far:

```
@Configuration
public class BaseAppConfig {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(Environment environment) throws IOException {
    String env = getEnvProperty(environment);
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocations(getPropertiesFiles(env));
    configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    return configurer;
  }
```

I tried a fancier `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`, but `convertPropertyValue()` is never called:

```
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {

      @Override
      protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue) {
        System.out.println("Parse " + originalValue);
        return super.convertPropertyValue(originalValue);
      }

    };
```

I tried to look into how Spring does its job and it seems that it works with `PropertyResolver`s. However, I don't see how I could weave one into that.

So how would I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's quite easy once I knew that [Spring's `RandomValuePropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/config/RandomValuePropertySource.html) was working exactly the way I intended.

Within minutes I was able to code a fancy duration configuration like

```
connection.connectTimeout=${duration:15s}
```

The missing link then is:

```
  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties(Environment environment) throws IOException {
    AbstractEnvironment standardEnvironment = ((AbstractEnvironment) environment);
    MutablePropertySources propertySources = standardEnvironment.getPropertySources();
    propertySources.addLast(new DurationValuePropertySource());
  }
```